# Group array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows and I need group type_id

```
array:11 [▼
  0 => {
    +"product_id": 521
    +"product_name": "Name product 1"
    +"type_id": 1
  }
  1 => {
    +"product_id": 521
    +"product_name": "Name product 1"
    +"type_id": 2
  }
  2 => {
    +"product_id": 521
    +"product_name": "Name product 1"
    +"type_id": 3
  }
  3 => {
    +"product_id": 526
    +"product_name": "Name product 2"
    +"type_id: 1
  }
  4 => {
    +"product_id": 526
    +"product_name": "Name product 2"
    +"type_id": 2
  }
]
```

I want to group the type_id into an array as follows:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {
    +"product_id": 521
    +"product_name": "Name product 1"
    +"type_id" : {
        0 => 1
        1 => 2
        2 => 3
    }
  }
  1 => {
    +"product_id": 526
    +"product_name": "Name product 2"
    +"type_id": {
        0 => 1
        1 => 2
    }
  }
]
```

I tried but couldn't group type_id . Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the array to `collection`, so that you can use collection method like [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby), [map](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map), [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck), [values](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-values)

```php
collect($array)->groupBy('product_id')->map(function($products) {
    $obj = clone $products->first();
    $obj->type_id = $products->pluck('type_id');
    return $obj;
})->values()->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution where $arr is your input array and $arrCollapsed the output array

```
$arrCollapsed = [];
foreach ($arr as $product) {
    if (false == isset($arrCollapsed[$product["product_id"]])) {
        $arrCollapsed[ $product["product_id"] ] = $product;
        $arrCollapsed[$product["product_id"]]["type_id"] = [ $product["type_id"] ];
    }
    elseif (false == in_array($product["product_id"]["type_id"], $arrCollapsed[$product["type_id"]])) {
        $arrCollapsed[$product["product_id"]]["type_id"][] = $product["type_id"];
    }
}
```